What is wrong with my pip instalation?
I reinstalled Ubuntu on my PC (version 24.0.1) via a bootable pen drive. Yesterday I installed vscode to write a python program for which I needed to install the rdflib library via pip. To do that I installed pip using the command 'sudo apt install pip pipx'. However, when I try to install the library itself this message appears.
I have already tried with other packages and now everything I install using pip causes this error.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you very much in advance.
Encountered issue
